# Why is my CAE architecture unable to learn anything despite a single colored repetitive noisy image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

This is my pytorch architecture, it takes colored 3x256x256 images as input

```
class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 channels : int,
                 latent_dim : int):

        super().__init__()
        ifac = 2
        lw = 2
        im = 2
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(channels, channels*2**1*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), #n 6 128 128
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Conv2d(channels*2**1*ifac, channels*2**2*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), #n 12 64 64
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Conv2d(channels*2**2*ifac, channels*2**3*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), #n 24 32 32
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Conv2d(channels*2**3*ifac, channels*2**4*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), #n 48 16 16
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Conv2d(channels*2**4*ifac, channels*2**5*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), #n 96 8 8
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Conv2d(channels*2**5*ifac, channels*2**6*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), #n 192 4 4
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Conv2d(channels*2**6*ifac, channels*2**7*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), #n 384 2 2
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Conv2d(channels*2**7*ifac, channels*2**8*ifac*lw, kernel_size=2, padding=0, stride=1), #n 768 1 1
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(channels*2**8*ifac*lw, 1024*im),
            nn.Tanh(),
            #nn.Linear(1024*im, latent_dim),
            #nn.Tanh(),
        ).cuda()

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            #nn.Linear(latent_dim, 1024*im),
            #nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(1024*im, channels*2**8*ifac*lw),
            nn.Tanh(),
            Reshape(-1, channels*2**8*ifac*lw, 1, 1),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**8*ifac*lw, channels*2**7*ifac, kernel_size=2, padding=0, output_padding=0, stride=1), #n 384 2 2
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**7*ifac, channels*2**6*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, output_padding=1, stride=2), #n 192 4 4
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**6*ifac, channels*2**5*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, output_padding=1, stride=2), #n 96 8 8
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**5*ifac, channels*2**4*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, output_padding=1, stride=2), #n 48 16 16
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**4*ifac, channels*2**3*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, output_padding=1, stride=2), #n 24 32 32
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**3*ifac, channels*2**2*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, output_padding=1, stride=2), #n 12 64 64
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**2*ifac, channels*2**1*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, output_padding=1, stride=2), #n 6 128 128
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**1*ifac, channels*2**0*ifac, kernel_size=3, padding=1, output_padding=1, stride=2), #n 3 256 256
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels*2**0*ifac, channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1), #n 3 256 256
            nn.Sigmoid()
        ).cuda()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
```

Training loop looks like this:

```
while True:
    avgloss = 0.0
    fac = 1.0 / len(tensor_batches)
    for batch_tensor in tensor_batches:
        #print(batch_tensor.size()) # -> torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 256]) 
        output_tensor = model(batch_tensor)
        loss = criterion(output_tensor, batch_tensor)
        avgloss = avgloss + loss.item()*fac
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    print(f"--- Loss: {avgloss:.4f} next epoch ---")
```

And produces images like this after the training converges (at a very high loss of like 0.1):

[image]

I would at least expect some random shapes and clouds in the output instead of a single color.
Also before training, shouldn't it produce a completely noisy (not repetitive) image with just the random weights ?

It only starts to somewhat generate something different (a blocky blurry version of the input image) if I remove all those smaller layers but the last 1 or 2.

I tried different activation functions, loss functions, optimizers and a bunch of different parameters.
Even if I train on like 4 pictures it cant produce anything else but a single average noisy color.
It looks like whenever I add the third layer (`channels*2**2*ifac` to `channels*2**3*ifac`) it breaks. I can even increase the channel size by a factor of 128, it doesnt make a difference.

How can I get a one dimensional latent space architecture with 256x256 images to work?

Comment: Plot training accuracy, loss vs epoc graphs for better understanding of learning and convergence.

Comment: I print the loss. It converges quite quickly against a high loss value. I just found out that if I add "BatchNorm2d" I can get 3 layers to work. Not sure why. Have to read about batch normalization. I am testing more layers now with that trick

Comment: You are compressing the features too much. Once the image is compressed to size 1x1, there is no way it will be reconstructed, and the weights learnt will have no meaning. As a trial, keep only 2 conv layers in encoder: 64x64 and 16x16 and only one conv layer in decoder: 64x64.

Comment: Afaik my code compresses it to about 3072 (channels*2**8*ifac*lw) features and not into one 1x1 image

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some `nn.BatchNorm2d(channels*2**6*ifac)` layers to my architecture.
Maybe the values blew up too much so it immediately saturated the network somewhere.